# Determinant of identity matrix minus exponential matrix $\det(I-k \exp (M)),$

Tags: determinant, matrix-exponential

I am currently struggling with the following determinant
$$\det(I-k \exp (M)),$$
where $I$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix, $M$ is a $2\times2$ matrix and $k$ is an arbitrary constant. Is there a general way of handling such objects?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Try starting from finding a decomposition for $M$, using diagonalization methods or else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Wolfram Mathematica code

```
Det@MatrixFunction[1-k*Exp[#]&,{{a,b},{c,d}}]//FullSimplify//TeXForm
```

which returns the result

$$-2 k e^{\frac{a+d}{2}} \cosh \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}\right)+k^2 e^{a+d}+1$$

and I have no reason to doubt its validity. As you can see, the
Mathematica function `MatrixFunction` does the hardest part of the job.

You can check the validity for diagonal matrices with

```
Det@MatrixFunction[1-k*Exp[#]&,{{a,0},{0,d}}]//Factor//TeXForm
```

which returns
$$\left(e^a k-1\right) \left(e^d k-1\right)$$
as it should.